# How to add a Arraylist in to a specific column of DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

How to add a Arraylist in to a specific column of DataTable, for example, add Arraylist of name 'mylist' to the 5th column of the DataTable name `mydatatable`.
I try this code:

```
foreach(string item in mylist)    
{    
  mydatatable.Rows.Add(item);    
}
```

But when i am using this code, the data always fill into first column of the table, and when I am adding column index or column name i am getting error message. So anyone have any idea about it? And Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
object[] fields = new object[5];
foreach(string item in mylist)
{
  fields[4] = item;
  mydatatable.Rows.Add(fields);
}
```